# How to set resource limits to accounts for each partition in accounting file in slurm

Tags: cluster-computing, slurm, hpc, sbatch, sacct

We have SLURM deployed on our cluster with several partitions (part_1, part_2, part_3). We have created several accounts in the accounting file and several users are part of each account. For each account, we have applied different resource limits (GrpTRES=node=3, GrpJobs=100 etc.)

Now, these limits, while working as expected, are being applied across all partitions. I want resource limits of each account to be applied only to the partition specified.

I have explored the man pages of sacctmgr, tried different solutions, asked chatgpt about it but don't seem to find a solution. Please let me know how can I achieve that?

Thanks,